# Styling jQuery mobile Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have very little experience with CSS.

I'd like to style the default [JQuery Checkboxes](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/forms/checkboxes/index.html) to move the checked icon from left to right.

I have used my badass Paint skills to illustrate what I'm looking for.

So I'm not asking for someone else to do the job, just some pointers in the right direction.

What would be the best way to achieve this ?

Thank you !

[image]

Comment: Well, i'm using the exact same checkboxes that are present on the Docs. page of Jquery here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/forms/checkboxes/index.html

Other than that, I tried playing directly in the JQuery css but only ended up breaking everything so I'm awaiting some pointers cause I have no idea how to achieve this and Google isn't really helping =/

Comment: I +1'd your question because of your badass Paint skills

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at the rendered output after jQuery Mobile parses your code using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

You will be able to see the structure and classes added to the form element. The class names added by jQuery Mobile are pretty strait-forward to understand.

--UPDATE--

Here is the HTML from firebug for the jQuery Mobile documentation for check-boxes:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical"><div class="ui-controlgroup-label" role="heading">Agree to the terms:</div><div class="ui-controlgroup-controls">

            <div class="ui-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="custom" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox-1"><label for="checkbox-1" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last ui-checkbox-on ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last"><span class="ui-btn-text">I agree</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-checkbox-on"></span></span></label></div>

        </div></fieldset>
    </div>
```

Notice the "ui-btn-icon-left" class, I'd play with that, you may not just be able to change it to "ui-btn-icon-right" but you can play with the structure. I've done this for other elements however I have not tested with check-boxes.

Comment: Ok.. so I get this <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow"></span> which is the little checkbox. But I still don't know how to move it from left to right.

Comment: Chaging it to right does the trick... that was more simple than I expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 20):

[jquery-mobile](/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile) v1.0 has a custom data attribute that you can use to adjust icon positioning. This includes checkboxes, radio buttons, nav bars, and other elements.

Documentation:
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

To create the checkbox you've drawn in your question above, your code would be:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-name" id="checkbox-id" />
  <label for="checkbox-id" data-iconpos="right">I agree</label>
```

Notice that `data-iconpos` is applied to the `label`. That's because jQuery Mobile styles this element heavily to act as the UI element in the front-end. In other words, with this attribute, you're positioning the checked/unchecked icon to the right side of the `label`.

Note: If you attempt to workaround this attribute and add `class="ui-btn-icon-right"` to your elements, jQuery Mobile may drop those classes when the page renders.

Answer (score 0):

This is now part of JQM using the standard APIs by setting `data-iconpos="right"`
See http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/checkboxradio-checkbox/#Iconposition for more details